# Exported Jar File In Eclipse is not executeable

Tags: java, eclipse

(Disclaimer: I have little clue what I'm doing so if I left out anything just ask)
In Eclipse I wrote this Hello World Program:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I exported it as a runnable jar file.
[Picture of runnable jar options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6gZ3.png)
[Picture 2 of runnable jar options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd9ql.png)

When I double click the jar file nothing happens. If I choose open with OpenJDK Platform Binary, nothing happens. using the command prompt:

```
$java -jar Test.jar
```

It runs fine.
If I decompress the Jar file I find a manifest file that looks correct:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Test
Class-Path: .
```

There's probably something basic that I'm missing but thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your Question to include exactly how do you try to run it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Why don't you take a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I think it could be useful for you and the community.